# How to make the table 2 * 2 with rules in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can I make the table with rules in my aspx page.

right now I am dispalying the page some thing like this.

```
Benefit Type :  000
Benfit Set:     BCPCP
Converage Level :   IND -Individual
Deductable Type :   D-DED
```

Can I differnciate with the rules each and every row. like this

```
Benefit Type :  000
```

---

```
Benfit Set:     BCPCP
```

---

```
Converage Level :   IND -Individual
```

---

```
Deductable Type :   D-DED
```

---

here is my Aspx code.. is there any way I can make like this?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a row with an hr in it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WXSpD/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Benefit Type:</td>
        <td>000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Benfit Set:</td>
        <td>BCPCP</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand, but if you're just looking for a two-by-two table, can't you do it like this?:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If there's something else you're looking for, can you clarify a little bit?